# Adding discipline to programmers.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0, subjective

Largely through inaction on our part, http://programmers.stackexchange.com has become a bit of a ... strange and undisciplined place.

We aim to fix this!

Our goal is to remove the bottom 15-20% of the "worst" programmers.se questions and disallow them as **not constructive subjective questions**. Robert is currently in the middle of composing a blog post about this, with a 4 or 5 factor test the community can use to determine if their subjective questions are either ...

1. good, in the sense that they provide useful information of some kind that others can potentially benefit from
2. bad, in the sense that they are amusing / entertaining but ultimately "junk food" empty experiences

So, please answer this question with:

1. **identify a "bad" programmers.se question, and tell us specifically *why* it is bad**.
2. **identify a "good" programmers.se question, and tell us specifically *why* it is good**.

(suggestion: check out the ["back it up" policy of moms4moms](http://moms4mom.com/back-it-up) which might inform your opinion on a general strategy for producing USEFUL subjective discussions; that's really what this is about)

---

this is now policy for subjective questions as documented on the blog:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

the cleanup of programmers.se begins this week and will continue:
[The Six Subjective Question Guidelines -- Enforcement Notice](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice)

Comment: ::stifles manic chortling::

Comment: Coming soon on area51: not "not programing related" related...

Comment: I thought programmers.se was **supposed to be** undisciplined. I thought it was a place where bad questions went to die. No?

Comment: **Are we posting example questions, or actual questions?**

Comment: @George: well, empirically speaking, three of us are posting actual questions, and one of us is posting example questions.

Comment: I knew it was only a matter of time. http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/213/how-can-we-avoid-programmers-se-from-becoming-the-se-black-sheep

Comment: I have a vision of someone trying to close the barn door after not only the horses, but also the unicorns and Tony the Pony have bolted.

Comment: belongs on meta.programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: (seriously though, why is this on the main meta site?)

Comment: @kip because ultimately it covers "how to have a subjective site". We think there will be more.

Comment: Wizards of LambdaMOO anyone? http://www.cc.gatech.edu/classes/AY2001/cs6470_fall/LTAND.html, it shouldn't be a surprise that the herd ran wild after you basically tore down the gates.

Comment: @Lasse, I read that entire contents of the page you linked. I don't understand the details of what LambdaMOO is, exactly, but I think I understood the gist of the thing. But if I'm interpreting correctly, you're saying that we should leave all the big decisions up to SOIS; is that accurate?

Comment: @Jeff, I've never used moms4mom, but that "back it up" policy is pure junk. In the first half, they say that "I'm a [insert profession here] and..." is bad because "there's no way we can validate who you are in real life." Then in the second half, they turn around and say "I had the same problem you are having when my little one was that age" is good, but it's equally unverifiable!

Comment: @popular I'm not sure you're understanding it. It's the difference between "you should do this because I am an accredited expert" and "I tried this, let me tell you a story about what happened and you can judge for yourself."

Comment: I'm tired of you all... you start building places which are not fun to be in.  Policies, separation, orders (!) for selecting "bad" questions...  I think you're ahead of time: robots still *have not* overtaken humanity, and we, the humans, are going to contribute to these sites!..

Comment: This "worst 15%" (i.e. acknowledging most aren't bad) is one of the top reasons I haven't felt compelled to participate on Programmers, though I really wasn't aware of it until you put it into words.

Comment: @Pop: I had the same problem you were having when I was running a huge Q&A network, and...

Comment: @Popular: I'm not a moms4mom user, but my understanding is "I experienced this while working as a professional \_\_\_ and what happened was..." fulfills their criteria.  It also feels like a slippery slope to me, but it's much like we do on SO: your words/ideas/code (your experiences with kids) stand on their merits and claiming to be a professional isn't enough.

Comment: @Gnome (and @Jeff), ah, but that's exactly the difference. With code, at least in many cases, you can look at what the OP wants to do, write a method, run it through a compiler and see if what comes out is right. There's no need to rely on claims that "I've been working with C since you were five." Your code can stand on its own; your claim that your kids were exactly the same as someone else's can't.

Comment: @Popular: There are still *many* statements on SO that are hard—effectively impossible for new programmers—to evaluate; many claims about optimization come to mind immediately.  And the m4m approach is the same as SO: "give it a try based on my code/experiences, find out more about it using my code/experiences as a guide, and see how it works for you."  Talking solely from a self-proclaimed position of authority ("I'm a professional and this is what you must do") doesn't fly on either site.

Comment: @Popular - the thing is, the questions on Moms4Mom may be 'subjective', but the answers *are* often useful - so it's not quite the same as the interesting-discussion-but-not-actually-doing-any-work-right-now stuff on p.se

Comment: @Benjol, I don't think the m4m approach works for any site, including but not limited to Programmers.SE. Stated differently, they ban "I'm a [job description] and I've seen this before; the answer is [whatever]" in all cases __except__ the one where [job description] is "parent," then suddenly it's a great answer. That's ridiculous; I don't have kids, but I could easily create an account, claim to be a parent of three kids and start spouting nonsense in answers about how my imaginary kids had the same problem and I solved it by feeding them a vegetarian diet (for a random example).

Comment: @Gnome, you're absolutely right, there are many complex SO questions. I oversimplified to make my point clearer. To me, this seems analogous to saying "don't tell us your background in programming, we can't verify it and it doesn't matter... _unless_ you have 12 years of experience in ANSI C, in which case we'll pay extra-special attention."

Comment: @Popular: TBH, I viewed the m4m policy very skeptically when I first saw it.  It was only reading this post that I saw the distinction above.  (With very little thought in-between... since I can't be a m4m user.)

Comment: @Popular, no, I'm not saying you should leave everything in the hands of the users. All I'm saying is that you shouldn't be surprised by how it turned out, it's not like things like this haven't been tried before, and documented. That's all I'm saying :)

Comment: @Lasse, okay, I can get on board with that. (also, SOIS = Stack Overflow Internet Services = the admins, not the users)

Comment: I rather like how it is right now. Its fun and wacky. Its the SE site i go to most.

Comment: DISLIKE!!! There is too much discipline/moderation on SE sites in general, it's nice there's one site which isn't so heavily controlled.

Comment: I wonder why this isn't on meta.programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: closed as too localized??? This is Jeff Atwood who posted this. He posts what he likes.. Nobody closes his questions..

Answer (score 32):

**please don't stamp out ALL the fun!**

I agree with cleaning things up a bit, but I was hoping programmers.se might be a nice place with a slightly looser dress code to discuss some fun things that won't be valuable academically but will be very valuable in making people laugh, bringing the community together, and making people's lives happier. Obviously this is not acceptable on stackoverflow, so I thought it might pass on this different site designed to be a slightly subjective.

If I am completely wrong and programmers.se was meant to be absolutely nothing but academically valuable questions, vote this post down and I'll delete it. :)

Comment: I think its more of people who have such a narrow minded view of SO, and any attempt to break that view/tradition is stiffly voted against. But what I don't like is that the community used the community tools to create a community site, and then a handful of people try to shut it down. Its sad really.

Comment: we want to cull the worst 15% of the questions, like I said in the post.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Isn't that what voting is for? The garbage will get voted down/voted to close.

Comment: @user132214: Yes, but even on SO we do have close **REASONS**.

Answer (score 23):

I haven't been a participant for very long there, but it is my understanding that there are actually several categories of questions that were *meant* to exist on Programmers.SE AKA "Not Programming Related", all of which make sense to keep.

---

## Good Topics

### Subjective Questions about Software Development

These are questions that actually **are**, *sort of*, about programming, but are just too subjective/open to have a home on Stack Overflow.  Examples are:

- [What features would you like to see in .NET version 5?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/279/3249)  (now deleted)

  We actually had this exact question on Stack Overflow, which never should have been allowed to exist.  It's *clearly* relevant to programmers and only programmers, it's just not helping anybody actually get things done.
- [How much effort should we spend to programming for multiple cores?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7000/3249)

  Another one that's way, way into the subjective camp and would (or at least should) be closed as S&A on Stack Overflow.  But still a topic worth "discussing" - if you're into discussion.
- [What differentiates the exceptional programmers from the really good ones?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/what-differentiates-the-exceptional-programmers-from-the-really-good-ones)

  Super subjective, but theoretically might help people to become better programmers.

### Personal Experiences and "War Stories"

These aren't appropriate for a Q&A site - they have no right or wrong answers or even really any *good* or *poor* answers, but they do sometimes have educational value.  Canonical example:

- [Worst coding standard you've ever had to follow?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1338/3249)

I don't think that any further explanation is warranted or required for this category.  Moving on...

### Career Advice / Business of Programming

Highly contentious on Stack Overflow, many people don't want the questions there, and they fit great on Programmers.SE.  Some high-voted examples are:

- [Job hopping, is it a problem?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3272/3249)

  Great example of a *practical* career advice question, where particularly good answers might actually affect somebody's decision-making for the better.
- [I've stopped coding for fun, is this a bad sign?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3558/3249)

  Not so practical, but at least relatively specific to programmers.  I should note that this is a *bit* borderline as it could apply to many professions, but programmers are particularly notorious for having work-related hobbies; you don't find many doctors practicing medicine for fun or accountants filing tax returns for fun.
- [Why do programmers write apps and then make them free?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3233/3249)

  Seems like a legitimate curiosity question that surprisingly *didn't* erupt in F[OS]S wars.  The top answer, while rather trite, is actually a good one.

### Resources

Technically, some of these questions might go on Stack Overflow, but Programmers is probably a better place for any *new* questions about "sites/books/authors/feeds to buy/read".  Quick examples:

- [What are some good programming cheat sheets?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3684/what-are-some-good-programming-cheat-sheets)
- [As a software engineer, who should I be following on Twitter?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135/as-a-software-engineer-who-should-i-be-following-on-twitter)

---

## Gray Area Topics

### Fun

I'm not sure if these should exist or not.  There's an endless variety of topics and many of the answers really have very little to do with programming (or programmers) at all.  Nevertheless, this category is probably half of what's attracting people to the site in the first place, so eliminating them could cause... problems.

Obvious examples:

- [What is your favorite “programmer” cartoon?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154/what-is-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) (10k)
- [What's your favorite programming joke?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35/whats-your-favorite-programming-joke) (10k)

---

## Bad/Useless Topics

### Work Environments

I find these useless because they're almost never specific to programming.  Take questions like these:

- [What coworker habit do you find most annoying?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4460/what-coworker-habit-do-you-find-most-annoying) (10K)

  This really has nothing whatsoever to do with programming or programmers.  Almost all of the answers could apply to any job/profession.
- [What music do you code to?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/344/what-music-do-you-code-to) (10k)

  This isn't merely subjective, it's a pure opinion poll.  Heavy metal as one of the highest-voted answers?  Yeah, OK.

### Holy Wars

There's even a bloody *tag* for it.  I know people love to argue on the internet, but frankly, I think they make the site look bad.  You don't want people to visit the site and get angry.

- [Which programming language do you really hate?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/which-programming-language-do-you-really-hate) (10k)

  Seriously?  Come on, get over it.
- [Do programmers have higher tendency to be atheists than non programmers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/do-programmers-have-higher-tendency-to-be-atheists-than-non-programmers-closed) (10k)

  Now closed, and with good cause.  I don't think I need to explain why.

---

I've gotta run now but I think that's a decent set of examples for the time being.

Comment: Good write-up! I rather suspect the last *three* categories are a huge part of the site's current popularity though...

Comment: The jokes and cartoons definitely are related to programming and software development (any answers that aren't should be downvoted); I don't see why that's a gray area.  Re work environment, do we really want all the various cubicle-hell pet peeves from any profession, plus any from jobs like secretary to delivery driver?  "What version control practice do you find annoying?" would be more acceptable where "coworker habit" isn't.  In contrast, "music while coding" is more bent towards programming, but not by much.

Comment: +1 for the "differentiates the exceptional programmers" example.

Comment: @Gnome: "music while coding" is about as programming-related as "snacks while coding" - which is to say, not very related. I'm sure there are some folks who think their setup is what makes them the Programming Gods that they are, and nothing but the right music, food, equipment, co-workers and ambient light will do... But I suspect most of these are just GTKY questions.

Comment: @Shog9: I know where you're coming from, and I 99% agree (I qualified "not by much" about "music"), but there are fewer jobs that let you listen to anything you want and where creativity can be important than there are where you can eat while at work.  (Of course, not all programming jobs let you listen to anything you want, but it seems to me—though I've only worked in a handful of professions—this is much higher than average for programmers.)

Comment: I'm not sure about the atheist question, though I know it could quickly degrade.  Compare to other [religious comparisions](http://blog.okcupid.com/index.php/the-real-stuff-white-people-like/) (about halfway down; post itself also deals with race).

Comment: @Gnome: I've only had a few different lines of work, so can't speak authoritatively on this... But the sole job where I couldn't listen to music involved answering phones (so, kinda obvious). Factory, farm, even janitorial work were all fairly tolerant of a radio or something at workstations, so long as it didn't interfere with work or communication. This strikes me as another instance of "programmer exceptionalism" - programmers thinking programmers are special because they're programmers.

Comment: @Shog9: For my 1% disagreement, I'm picturing headphones and isolation—definitely interfering with communication and much less common in other jobs, rather than a radio an entire office can share, but I suppose this may reflect how I tick more than anything.

Comment: @Gnome: I prefer a good amp and great big speakers cranked up **loud...** Which probably explains why I *didn't* picture headphones. That said, "Can listening to music interfere with your job?" might actually make a decent P.SE question... though I'm hardly surprised that no one has asked it.

Comment: Oh man, you wouldn't believe [the amount of flak the locking of the atheist question got on Meta.Programmers.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/285/please-lets-not-lock-questions-unless-as-an-absolute-last-resort). It's the textbook case of how Programmers.SE has gotten derailed due to lack of discipline.

Comment: @Gnome: *"Do we really want all the various cubicle-hell pet peeves from any profession, plus any jobs like secretary to delivery driver?"* - *No*, that's why I listed it under the "bad" heading.

Comment: @Aarobot: I was agreeing with you on that, then leading into the contrast on the version-control hypothetical question.

Comment: @Shog: I suspect you're right about all of the "bad" topics being largely responsible for the site's popularity; the trick, of course, is finding a set of topics that can sustain *some* popularity without turning it into an intellectual wasteland.  Once you eliminate all of the garbage GTKY-type questions, there still seems to be a pretty *large* number of real (albeit subjective) programming/programmer questions.

Comment: @Gnome: I gotcha.  Yes, I didn't make any mention of any version control question but I suppose that a discussion of version control practices would be appropriate.  It is, after all, completely specific to programming, and as far as I know it's not in any holy-war territory.  On the other hand, a question about "annoying IT policies" would be borderline because most of the answers would be "No Facebook" or some other NPR crap.

Comment: @Aarobot: That IT policies example gives me a good heuristic: answers should be written from the point of view of a *programmer,* not someone who just happens to be in a cubicle, in front of a computer, etc.  If a question engenders too much of that, it's probably off-topic.  (E.g. the beer answer mentioned elsewhere is written from the point of view of someone that likes beer.)

Comment: @Gnome: are you implying there are programmers who don't like beer? Where'd I put that torch and pitchfork...

Comment: @Shog: I think he was implying that *everybody* likes beer, irrespective of their vocation.

Comment: @Aarobot: then surely the old SO rule of thumb (question could be asked of any or all professions without necessarily changing the answers) could apply... I don't see why a question should be dinged for off-topic *answers* unless the question *itself* is off-topic.

Comment: @Shog: I agree, that answer even got voted down (although maybe that happened after this meta discussion was made?).  As long as the question makes it explicit how it's specific to programmers (i.e. an "interesting" location should have attractions that are *uniquely* of interest to programmers) then it's alright.  On the other hand, if *almost every* answer ends up being off-topic then the question was probably too vague (and the crap answers likely make it unsalvageable).

Comment: @Shog9: Questions that could be answered programming-specifically are closed on SO if they are asked in a way that leads to too much non-programming answers.  But from the start I thought this was the general way Programmers.SE was going to be different: programming/er *related* rather than programming *specific.*  @Aarobot: Yes, it was +2 or +3, I think, when that question and answer were brought up on a different answer here.

Comment: @Aarobot: Heh, the down-votes happened after this post was made... IMHO, that question highlights a problem with just tacking "for programmers" and such onto otherwise general-purpose questions: programmers are still a subset of *everyone else*, so you're gonna get some of the same answers as the broader question. My first thought upon seeing that question was of all the great vacation tips a programmer had given me regarding the Los Angeles / SoCal area... None of which involved computer history or overtly "geeky" tourist attractions.

Comment: @Gnome: well, that impression appears to be in question here... We'll see, I guess.

Comment: @Shog: The answers to that question are programmer-relevant though; it's all in the wording of the question.  If the question is simply *"What are good vacation spots for programmers?"* then that's off the table.  If it's *"What destinations have attractions about programming, computer science, or other topics of interest to programmers?"*, that should be fine.  Every SE site has its gray areas; the "for programmers" suffix is going to be a major one here.  Some "for programmers" topics simply can't be edited into anything useful, like Music or Snacks.

Comment: @Aarobot: the original question was simply, "Programmer Travel Guide", and prior to the attention focused on it by *this* question, it had two "comp. hist." answers, two "good food/drink" answers, one "geeky but not programming-related" answer, and one "Microsoft" answer (which I guess is programming-related, but not totally clear on why that would be a good tourist attraction). I'm sure it *could* have been crafted into a strictly-programming-related question ("What comp. hist. locations should I visit?", etc.) but even with the bump it's still just "interesting locations *for programmers*"

Comment: I'm not sure I can say "fun" is a gray area on p.se. *IF* you buy that "programming culture" questions fit, then I think most of these fall into that.I think the work environment tag just needs more definition: "what colors for your ide" or "how much lighting is best" seem to be perfectly ok to me. But the questions you highlight are indeed lousy. If it were up to me, I'd also just auto-ban people who asked anything that smelled of holy war. One of the things attracting me to SO is the fairly neutral ground it stands on.

Comment: @Shog: Well, obviously we're experiencing a bit of the HUP here, but that's probably a good thing.  Part of this process is working out not only what *types of questions* are okay, but what *formulations of questions* make sense.

Comment: @Jim: I explained why I consider it gray area.  It's because even though Programmers.SE is for *subjective* questions/discussions, it's still (as far as I know) intended to be an *information resource*, and such questions only constitute "information" by the loosest possible definition.  Bottom line is, those questions aren't helping anyone to become a better programmer.  Nevertheless, they're part of the draw of the site, as your comment proves.

Comment: @Aarobot - I guess part of my thinking on it is that SO has historically seen a lot of the "fun" questions get tons of upvotes, so I see little chance of p.se doing putting the thumb in the dike.

Comment: @Jim: As we all know, upvotes mean something entirely different for those types of questions and you really can't compare polls to actual *questions*, you can only compare them to each other.  "Fun" questions, though, may actually be in yet *another* category, because they're basically mindless amusement.  I'm just hypothesizing here, but I think that most people will only upvote a discussion if they find it somewhat thought-provoking, whereas they upvote "fun" polls just for the hell of it.

Comment: I've just read [Do programmers have higher tendency to be atheists than non programmers?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/do-programmers-have-higher-tendency-to-be-atheists-than-non-programmers-closed). Risky topic, but without inflammatory responses, some quoted studies, some self references and others public references, it doesn't look a bad question...

Answer (score 16):

**Good questions**

[“Comments are a code smell”](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1/comments-are-a-code-smell)

Bad question for SO, because we've decided that SO's no good for extended, contentious discussions, but *perfect* for p.se - it's an issue all programmers run into, especially those fresh out of schools whose professors told them to comment every line. Really understanding good commenting/documentation practice will make one a better developer.

[How do you learn your way around an undocumented project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6829/how-do-you-learn-your-way-around-an-undocumented-project)

Old hands giving tips to the yung-uns. Anecdotes and stories that might end up being helpful to someone.

**Bad questions**

[What programmer/geek/nerd stereotypes are true/false for you?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4820/what-programmer-geek-nerd-stereotypes-are-true-false-for-you)

Because it's both a poll (often bad news), and contains no useful content. Pure junk food.

[Could you recommend some interesting cities/locations that a programmer should visit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264/could-you-recommend-some-interesting-cities-locations-that-a-programmer-should-vi)?

This question *might* go in a good direction - computer museums, corporate campuses - but when "go to my town, it's got good beer" gets voted up, no. Again, just personal information, nothing useful to programming.

The answers to the "bad" question contain nothing that could improve my experience, skills, or knowledge about programming. *Off-topic* is one thing - that's why programmers.se exists. *Contributes nothing that could be used for the betterment of the readership* is another.

Possible close reasons:

- Pointless
- Does not contribute to the overall weal
- This is not Facebook
- Nothing here helps me do my job better
- Not programming related (*wait - dammit!*)
- Not related to programming or software development in the slightest
- Not appropriate to yell over your cube wall

Comment: what's the general question class -- "getting to know you"? contains only personal information like "height, weight, age, favorite color.."?

Comment: @Jeff: Not sure what you mean - are you asking how to generally categorize these kinds of questions? How about "A/S/L"? "Contains nothing that might conceivably improve the practice of programming"?

Comment: @Jeff we originally called them "poll" questions on Programmers.SE. Then people started calling them "survey" questions. I get what "getting to know you" question means, but that might be a little too...insidery?...for a new user.

Comment: Poll questions aren't bad on Programmers.SE. If you look at it, all subjective questions are polls, which is exactly what the site was made for.

Comment: @TheLQ: I tend to agree with you. More of the problem, I think, is "not related to programming or software development in the slightest" questions.

Comment: @Jeff: Perhaps it's just an unfortunate side-affect of being a genius, but your comments are often indecipherable.  Could you be less vague?  Yes, many of us are morons, but we're trying to get smarter.  You seem to think you can convey a message to us plebeians in fewer words than you actually need to use.  Perhaps you've forgotten the size of the audience you're addressing?

Comment: What's wrong with polls?  They convey potentially interesting information.  Moreover, what's with this "must help me program better" stuff?  How about "must help me understand programmers"?

Comment: @raven: He's looking to generalize the undesirable traits of the examples given. These aren't really *poll* questions except in the loosest sense - there's usually no intention or effort made to compile the results, and there's no possible way to make them statistically valid. It's a form of question occasionally referred to as GTKY (Getting To Know You), intended primarily as a way of familiarizing yourself with *other users of the site*, like those little questionnaires that get passed around on blogs or Facebook. So are these inherently undesirable, or only when they veer too far off-topic?

Comment: @Michael I'm the poster of the question about the cities a Programmer should visit. Actually I've downvoted a couple of "come to my city" answers and asked to submit some links to enrich the answer too. Why are you judging a question from the answers given?

Comment: @system: Removing "cities" and focusing on locations would make that a much better question—and should eliminate any "come to my city" answers.  (AIUI, focusing on that is what you currently mean, but "cities" just distracts.)

Comment: @Gno [done](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/264/could-you-recommend-some-interesting-locations-that-a-programmer-should-visit)

Comment: @systempuntoout: Relax, I'm not proposing that you be punished. Some questions inspire good, useful answers. Others don't.

Comment: @Michael uh, I am relaxed.

Comment: How about **not programmer related** as a close reason?  The site is subjective, but it still has a topic/goal.  **Not useful** ("pointless or noise" from here) could cover the stereotype question, but I'm undecided on whether it's a bad question in the first place.  (The locations question isn't bad, but the "good beer" answer is for the reasons you mentioned; i.e. "might go in a good direction" as you said.)  **Argumentative** (without subjective) could be another.

Comment: Hate away, but just gonna say... I'd rather drink good beer while discussing Turing's work with Portlandians than drink English beer while staring at his old job site.

Comment: @Shog9: Do you have a particular programmer-related event that occurs periodically (or even just upcoming once) in Portland?  When and where can I meet these Porlandian programmers?  A 10 person user-group/fan-club probably isn't going to cut it, but naming any convention targeted (at least a little bit) to programmers would reverse the reasons that's an inappropriate answer.  This is the emphasis on locations (which can be programmer related) and not cities (which cannot).

Comment: @Gnome: can I get in on that? There's one place I go in Portland (actually, out in the burbs) where I can usually find someone to discuss ~Turing. Pretty place, grass and all that, but it gets tired.

Comment: @Michael: Is it an event? Or just this bar with this guy you know?  (Hey, even a bar next to the CompSci department at a university *might* be enough.)  Tell us how it's programmer related.

Comment: @Gnome: Nope - I don't live in Portland, nor do I go there for work. But as a tourist destination, it has to be one of my favorites - I've never failed to have a good time, and every local I've met has been fun to talk with. I don't *plan* my vacations, so ad-hoc enjoyment counts for a lot with me.

Comment: @Gnome: you go to *this* bar, you'd *know* it's programmer related. But no, not really.

Answer (score 16):

Damn, I had to upvote [Kop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65437/adding-discipline-to-programmers-stackexchange-com/65449#65449). Jeff, you ruined my day.

I really do not know what the issue is here. People complained that SF and SU were used as trash bins for SO content. Well, they were, because there is a *need* for such a trash can. Someone was smart enough to propose such a can and now you want to clean it up? Are you serious?

Jeff, you are proposing community-driven sites all the time (even so we know it better). So let the Programmer.SE guys care about it. They know best, what to do with their site.

Comment: This. Watching the folk who pushed so incessantly for trashing SO split hairs over the relative inanity of questions on P.SE is irony so rich I had to pour myself another cup of coffee just to wash it down...

Answer (score 13):

I don't get it.

Programmers is by **a *HUGE* margin** the most successful area51 proposal ever. It has double the pageviews of any other proposal, and will soon surpass server fault.

What's the only difference between programmers and the other dozens less successful proposals? That it is, as you call it, undisciplined.

So why change it?

<sup>Note: to avoid being too verbose I'm replacing "with the most page views" with "successful". Whether it's successful or not is subjective, but let's not get into that. With the terminology of this post successful just means "having more views".</sup>

Comment: I'm going to have to compile the activity, it does seem much better than other sites.

Comment: I'm on the fence about this. I suspect Jeff wants to retain the "professionalism" that the other sites exhibit, and avoid having p.se become a forum. His definition of successful is not (purely) pageviews. I dunno - p.se is kinda fun, like the occasional slice of pizza.

Comment: @Micheal: exactly. It's **one** website, can't Jeff just leave it as it is? He often blogs about making the internet a better place, if a lot of people are having *fun* with an "undisciplined" website, then it makes the internet better.

Comment: I don't see how having an undisciplined Q&A "forum" makes the internet a better place given the premise that Yahoo! Answers, exactly what you're looking for, is massively successful and doesn't make the internet a better place. If anything, a massively successful "forum" SE site is like [Transformers: Revenge of the Fallen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Revenge_of_the_Fallen): categorically awful for everyone, but a massive cash-in.

Comment: @Michael The issue with that is Programmers.SE **is a professional site.** We (mostly) give legitimatize answers to legitimate questions. You have exceptions (XKCD, the entire closed list), but you don't see us giving mispelled and uncapitalized answers or questions most of the time. We are professional. **Subjective doesn't mean not professional.**

Comment: @TheLQ: please define "professional" in this context. Keep in mind open questions like [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/4820/what-programmer-geek-nerd-stereotypes-are-true-false-for-you) and answers like [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/264/could-you-recommend-some-interesting-cities-locations-that-a-programmer-should-vi/777#777) (he's right about Portland, btw. Great beer).

Comment: @TheLQ: Look. I like programmers.se. It's fun. But let's not fool ourselves. It's not a professional site, not in the normal sense of the word. Would you feel ok calling a meeting at work to discuss any of the topics on the site? If no, it's not professional.

Comment: @Michael Perhaps because you don't call a meeting based on what some anonymous person said on a website? I don't think people call meetings based on SO, nor any SE site. But lets define professional: "engaged in a profession or engaging in as a profession or means of livelihood" Thats pretty much Programmers.SE, where we specifically talk about that. SO does that. SF does that. SU (sorta) does that. The only one that doesn't is gaming.

Comment: @TheLQ: Wow, you sit around your office all day talking about beer and how you live in your mother's basement? Certainly different than my office. And I still challenge the link you're making between the definition of the word "professional" and much of the content of p.se.

Comment: @TheLQ: Nothing inherently wrong with the site as it is. Nothing wrong with a site that's geared towards content of professional interest. Can't have both, though. If you want the latter, some of the content's got to go, and the rules around new content need to be tightened up.

Comment: @TheLQ Are trying to say that Gaming is unprofessional because of its subject matter, or because of how the community conducts itself?

Comment: @Grace: by the definition he presented, I assume it's the former (subject matter).

Comment: @michael like I said in the post, we just want to remove the 15-20% of worst questions, and inject some more meaty topics like testing. The site is mostly OK, it just needs some stewardship and parenting, which we've been doing a poor job with so far on programmers.se specifically.

Answer (score 12):

First, let me say, *thank you*. A cleanup is sorely needed.

**Bad Question:** [The lifecycle of "cool"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311/the-lifecycle-of-cool)

It's bad because it takes 271 words to expand upon a flawed premise (that people only use Textmate and jQuery because of herd behavior) only to ask two questions that essentially amount to "aren't I right? Why am I right?" There are a lot of questions like this on Programmers.SE, and they only serve to provide an outlet to people who want to rant.

**Good Question:** [Job hopping, is it a problem?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/job-hopping-is-it-a-problem)

It's a question about programmers that isn't programming, doesn't pre-suppose a worldview in the question, and can elicit dozens of good answers without having a definitive one. If only all questions on Programmers.SE were like it.

Basically, beyond the "getting to know you" style questions, the *bad* questions on Programmers.SE are the ones that pre-suppose a worldview and ask for confirmation or reasons why that worldview is correct. The only thing they succeed in doing is re-hashing the talking points for the position the asker espouses and pissing off everyone who doesn't agree.

Comment: I do think some questions end up being rants, but we mostly close those as "Not a real question" anyway. And besides, it is a subjective question since people are looking for alternatives to their view. And such alternatives might change their view for the better, which is our end goal anyway.

Comment: @TheLQ the goal of a SE site isn't to convert people to one's cause. It's to provide useful information (in the form of questions and answers) to visitors. Subjective or extended questions *can* be useful to people: they can find out how complex an issue is by the diverging answers. But the rant questions only serve one use to a passerby, and that's to inform them that the question asker is an a-hole.

Comment: The given bad question is bad because it's poorly phrased.  There's a good question lurking in there (and in far fewer words).  The question of why tools get popular, and some get extremely popular, is an interesting one, and not really suited for SO.

Answer (score 12):

...so you go and cull the "bottom 15-20%," whatever you determine that to be, and then what?  It's not going to change the people on the site, and it's not going to change the nature of the questions that get posted there, and even if it did, how much notice would people take?

When I was growing up, a friend's mother always thought that the TV was too loud whenever we were watching TV.  Now, kids tend to like to have their TV and their music a bit louder than they probably should, but this was not rooted in any objective criteria.  She just had it in her head that the TV was too loud, and she'd make us turn it down.  And then, maybe 15 minutes later, she'd notice it again and say the TV was too loud, and make us turn it down further, and so on and so on until we couldn't hear a thing.  (Even though we had not been turning it back up when she didn't notice.  She'd do this even if she was watching something together with us.)

If people start to get it in their heads that the bottom 15-20% need to be cleaned out, I guarantee that they're going to come back later and clean out the bottom 15-20% of whatever's left.  And there's only so many times you can do that before all those percentages start to add up to a significant fraction, and suddenly you've detroyed the most successful Area51 community ever.

Programmers was designed explicitly to be a place where the normal rules are inside out, and it's been a huge hit.  That's a pretty good sign that it ain't broke; don't "fix" it please.

Comment: Eventually, you only have one question left... But it's **the best question ever asked**!

Comment: so "it ain't broke" also means "so perfect it is impossible to improve"? I think not, my friend.

Comment: @Jeff: Not "impossible to improve" so much as "unnecessary to improve."  We're getting deep into "premature optimization" territory here, especially considering the heavy-handed behavior I've seen so far by mods locking productive discussions that the participants even cared about enough to reopen after they'd been closed.  No actual improvement is taking place by trying to "clean things up."

Comment: @mason well, we'll have to agree to disagree on this then. We will be cleaning up the bottom 15-20% of questions and setting guidelines for productive-yet-subjective questions. If you find that disagreeable, perhaps there might be other sites on the internet, somewhere, that are more to your liking?

Comment: @Jeff: All I'm saying is that you're really focusing your efforts on the wrong thing.  As Kop points out, this is "by a HUGE margin the most successful area51 proposal ever."  Programmers is the only one that's come anywhere near duplicating the runaway success of the original StackOverflow.  Instead of trying to clean it up, you'd do a lot better to try to figure out how to quantify what makes it so special, and see if you can't add a little bit of that to the other StackExchange sites.

Comment: @mason we're not interested in popularity; that's a thread full of XKCD cartoons. What we are interested in creating professional sites that make the internet better. So expect more discipline on programmers in the very near future, and the bottom 15-20% of useless, non-professional questions on programmers.se to be closed mercilessly and with extreme prejudice.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood ~ Then can we have a watercooler.se?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood Is this an answer that follows FAQs guidelines? `We will be cleaning up (...) If you find that disagreeable, perhaps there might be other sites on the internet...`

Answer (score 11):

**I think that the main problem with Programmers.SE is a lack of shared vision.**

1. A lot of people see it as flowing from the original definition.  For example, of the top five on-topic questions, one is way too broad ("What are common mistakes in Software Development?") and two are joke questions.  I think P.SE has more or less expanded straight up from there- anything that isn't egregiously unrelated to programming (eg, "what are some good beers for programmers?") flies.  Until recently, the effort in meta.p.se had been going to defining exactly where that line was.
2. Mr. Atwood and co, on the other hand, see the future of Programmers.SE as a professional resource, and less of a stack exchange tavern.  A blog post mentioned a distaste for "stupid water-cooler nonsense" and a need for meatier discussion.

Either of these options are fine by me, and it looks like the latter is going to be imposed from above.

My point here is not to argue for or against a culling, but rather just to point out that the best way to raise the quality of questions on programmers.se is simply to present a clear vision for what the site should be like.

Comment: I applaud you. That's a fair, balanced and sane answer without emotions dripping from every letter.

Comment: If that's imposed, you know somebody's going to start an Area51 proposal for #1.  I'll probably do it if nobody else does.

Comment: @David Thornley http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21841/bad-subjective-programmers

Comment: This is a good and thoughtful answer . One point to add is that if you look at old stackoverflow questions, there were a lot of subjective / not programming related questions there originally and the community figured out over time what was allowed and what wasn't. Now questions on SO are closed quickly by the community, when they are off-topic but it took a while to figure out what "off-topic" meant. Programmers.se will find its voice, people just need to be patient. As long as the most active participants ask, answer and vote on questions that are good, the noise will disappear over time.

Answer (score 4):

OK. Trying to take the topic seriously (and not currently a participant on programmers):

- Reasoned opinions and advice based on experience are better than simple likes and dislikes or other pure opinions. That is [How do you learn your way around an undocumented project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6829/) is more helpful than [What are the most impressive tricks an IDE could pull off with the code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/).
- Specific comparisons are better than wide open holy wars. That is a (as yet mythical) question on what syntax highlighting features of vim are better or worse than those found in emacs is better than [Which is better? VIM vs Emacs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1271/which-is-better-vim-vs-emacs).

Meta rule:

If an xkcd comic is the highest rated answer the question is junk, but you won't be able to get rid of it. Too much fun.

Comment: XKCD comics being upvoted heavily is not because the question is junk, its because voting on Programmers.SE is an issue. I've seen many commeters saying they'll upvote later because they ran out of votes. People vote for what they like, and funny is something that most people like

Comment: The xkcd thing applied on SO ages ago. It's a occupational hazard. That's why you'll never get rid of them.

Comment: xkcd is often relevant to what programmers talk about, much like Dilbert used to be.  The author is often capable of saying things more eloquently than I can, and in some cases is saying just what I want to.  People quote Knuth; why not Randall Munroe?

Comment: @David: Sure. I read xkcd religiously. Hell, Randall has physicists nailed too, which I really appreciate (And it makes him by back-up source of science humor when Sid Harris lets me down). But once he makes an appearance people's mouse fingers start clicking by reflex.

Comment: I'd quote Munroe more often if he had a pipe organ in his home.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's ridiculous to be having this discussion here. As much as you feel that there is some *indiscipline* on programmers.se, the fact that you are having the discussion here on meta is just stupid.

It's one thing if you want to hash out some guidelines for all stack exchange sites here, but you don't. You are specifically asking for good and bad questions on another SE site *that has its own meta* which means that the people participating actively on programmers.se are not being asked for their opinion, but are being treated like your red-headed step child.

If people want to make programmers.se better, they should join in, ask and answer questions and use their votes. If people aren't interested in joining, that's not a problem, but we shouldn't be interested in non -participants opinions about what makes a good question and answer on another site, because it doesn't matter. Ironically, while I am an active participant on programmers.se, I can't even vote on these answers here because I don't have reputation on meta. So even though I am (or should be) part of your target audience for this conversation, I cannot cast my votes.

Jeff, if you view programmers as your indisciplined child, then do what a good parent would do: *[model good behaviour](http://ezinearticles.com/?How-Effective-Leaders-Model-Good-Behavior---Nu-Leadership-Series&id=342830).* Encourage others to model good behaviour, by asking good questions and giving good answers that will over time drown out the questions that you, personally, don't like. Don't do a drive by punishment by closing and locking questions to which the community have given time and upvotes. Eventually, these questions will stop being asked as the community grows and finds its way.

Please migrate this discussion to programmers.se where it belongs.

Comment: we did -- http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice

Comment: No you didn't. You posted the six subjective guidelines. That is not what you are doing here. You are asking for a poll of good and bad questions from one specific site that has its own meta. Why aren't you doing that on the site in question?

Comment: I actually compiled [a (non-exhaustive) list of all the times we discussed it on Meta.Programmers.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/396/question-being-closed-without-community-requests/401#401). Needless to say, but almost every single question on Meta dealt with this problem.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I still genuinely don't get why the poll question from Jeff asking for examples of good and bad questions from programmers.se happened here rather than on meta.programmers.se.

Answer (score 3):

#### Bad

[What's your experience with female programmers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3974/whats-your-experience-with-female-programmers)

At best, a pointless trading of anecdotes. At worst, an incubator for stereotypes. Can we expect "What's your experience with [Frenchmen|Jews|poor] programmers" to follow?

[What's the most absurd myth about programming issues?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1745/whats-the-most-absurd-myth-about-programming-issues)

At best, pointless chit-chat. At worst, flame-bait. And entirely too general ("programming issues"?) in any case.

[Worst coding standard you've ever had to follow?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions)

Chit-chat. And, The Daily WTF does it better.

...

#### Good

[“Comments are a code smell”](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1/comments-are-a-code-smell)

Not terribly well asked, but an honest question. Hopefully the author has some good counter-arguments to his co-worker's assertions now.

[How to respond when you are asked for an estimate?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/648/how-to-respond-when-you-are-asked-for-an-estimate)

A common problem for working programmers, and one often overlooked during training.

---

There are very, very few questions on Programmers that I think have any real value to them, apart from being somewhat fun to participate in. Of course, this was the *point* of Programmers.SE - it was proposed as a place for all the inane "what do programmers like?" questions that kept cropping up on SO! But if you're *determined* to get serious about this, I think aiming for the worst 15% is *entirely* too conservative: skim off the top 10%, and let the rest disappear.

Comment: If the decision is made to get serious about Programmers.se, the best thing to do would be to shut down the site entirely, and open SO up for more subjective questions.

Answer (score 0):

**A bad example**

- [What is better for coding - desktop or laptop?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/what-is-better-for-coding-desktop-or-laptop)

There are actually quite a few questions of this type, which I really dislike. This question is not interesting, because most people would find it rather *obvious* that a desktop computer is faster/more ergonomic/more functional than a laptop computer, but that laptops have the advantage of being mobile. What more is there to say, really? I get the feeling that the OP sort of wants to post a very general question hoping it to become highly popular and heavily up-voted. The answer with the highest score says

> Assuming you have an external monitor and keyboard to connect to your laptop the difference is small.

which anyone could have come up with.

Generally, "do not post questions that have predictable answers".

**A good example**

There are many good examples, so I feel it'd be silly to give examples, but here is one at least. I choose this particular one, because I think that many would *not* consider it a "good" example:

- [What's your favorite programming joke?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35/whats-your-favorite-programming-joke)

This is good because it is fun (and no, the answers are definitely not predictable!). It is not bad to have fun once in a while. This question would not fit on StackOverflow.com, but I think questions like this are fun enough at programmers.stackexchange.com (I refuse to write "programmers.se" because I live in Sweden, so for me, ".se" is a TLD).

<del>Also fun enough: [What things are essential on a programmer's desk?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/what-things-are-essential-on-a-programmers-desk)</del>

For completeness, I also give

**The ideal questions**

- What feature do you want to see in the next version of Delphi (say)?
- What are the lesser known but useful functions in the Delphi RTL (say)?
- [What syntax element do you hate most in a programming language you use frequently?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/501/what-syntax-element-do-you-hate-most-in-a-programming-language-you-use-frequently)

Comment: Got a bone to pick with "essential desk things" - the top answers are "monitors" and "writing instruments"; how does this not fit into the "obvious answers" category you established above? Heck, a good many of the answers are just standard office-worker paraphernalia...

Comment: Well, there are definitely obvious (bad) *answers* to this question. But there are also a few non-trivial things like *three* monitors, a whiteboard, (non-alcoholic) beverages, and a hairbrush. OK, it is just *barely* "fun enough", I give you that. First I considered using http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/cool-toys-for-geeks as the "fun enough" example, but the problem with this is that not all geeks are programmers. Still, I like the question, and would not want it removed from programmers."SE".

Comment: Beverages? Really? And... whiteboards are pretty standard office equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that isn't entirely responsive.

One of the puzzles of subjective questions on an SE site is reputation. We're all seen it -- subjective questions are vote magnets, and it warps the rep system.

If, by some means, the rep disparity could be controlled, it would remove one of the incentives for posting the questions you want to get rid of. Would that make a significant dent? Only an experiment would tell for sure -- if there was an alternative voting mechanism to try out.

OK, how about this? It's very different, but I think it would be better on a subjective site. Instead of everyone getting to vote up or down, and adding them all up, let everyone *rate*, and average them. The simplest rating system would look just like the voting system: -1, 0, 1. In other words, people go ahead and vote, but what results is the average, not the sum. Even if 500 people think that the question is totally rad, the resulting score is '1', and the reputation gain matches.

A more radical change would allow five possible ratings instead of three.

Comment: Sounds like the CodeProject forums... Only without the helpful threading.

Comment: No. 99% of all P.SE questions are not asked to be rep whores, and neither are 95% the answers. Changing the entire rep system for that 1% of questions and 5% of answers is stupid. Besides, many have tried to change the reputation system, and all have failed.

Answer (score -1):

**A bad example:**

> Vi vs. Emacs?

This is a bad question because it is flame bait as well as extremely subjective. There is virtually nothing useful to be learned from such a question.

**A good example:**

> Practical Differences Between VS2010 Ultimate and VS2010 Express?

This question is seeking factual advice for product differences. Nobody can contest facts and there is plenty to be learned from such a question.

Comment: needs more detail than this; just "can be contentious sometimes" isn't enough.

Comment: @Jeff: Okay. Give me a sec. to fix it up.

Comment: I thought these were precisely the questions that get booted to the cesspool of programmers.se. Wasn't that the entire point of the site?

Comment: I disagree. This type of debate is valuable to people like me who are new to both. We can't say a question is bad because we don't think people won't read the useful information contained in it. Whether the question is too broad is another issue.

Comment: @Jeff: There. I fixed it up a lot.

Comment: Its not flamebait people. http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/299/add-a-flamebait-close-reason

Comment: `There is virtually nothing useful to be learned from such a question.` => Except maybe all the pros and cons of both choices?

Comment: I see this (vi vs emacs) as a precisely *on-topic* question for p.se. Subjective, sure, but that's why the site's there. Talks about the tools programmers use. Presents reasons to use both.

Comment: @Michael: I still say flamebait.

Comment: You have the right to, @George.

Comment: @Michael: As I see it emacs vs. vi in general is mostly flamebait. Pro and cons of implementations of specific features is another matter. Also possibly cultural differences promoted or supported by them. They is room to discuss these matters, but...

Comment: Questions like Vi(m) VS Emacs can be seen as good if you change it in such way that it provides people with a clear overview of why to choose for one editor, this way people can learn from the differences and thus the question could have an useful purpose... Maybe we should have rules against flame baits on such question or a rule on how such questions should be posed.

Comment: Is there any reason why I shouldn't ask about significant differences between VS2008 and VS2010 on Stack Overflow itself?  If "good" programmers.se questions are the ones that fit on SO, what's programmers.se for?

Comment: I think the motive of the asker also needs to be weighed in flame-bait questions. IF the question is "what's better", then it's likely just a rep gamer. If the question is "I need to pick java or c# for a project, which should I choose?" Then I think the asker is likely to actually be looking for some opinions, not just trolling for rep.