# When are specific site proposals off-topic on Area 51 Discussions?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I noted that we have a [specific-proposal](/questions/tagged/specific-proposal) tag. Looking at the questions, I found that it is for specific Area 51 site proposals.

I decided to write some tag wiki contents, but got stuck when I wanted to discuss the scope. Questions about specific proposals normally belong on Area 51 Discussions. The Help page for Area 51 Discussions simply links to a [single FAQ page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) for Area 51 itself. It does not discuss the scope of Area 51 Discussions.

So the question is about the scope of Area 51 Discussions.

**When should a question about a specific site proposal be asked on Area 51 Discussions, and when should it be asked on Meta Stack Exchange?**

A little overlap is normal, but are there clear boundaries that we can establish here?
Is there a reasonable scenario where a question about a specific site proposal would be *off* topic on Area 51 Discussions? Or can they practically always go on Area 51 Discussions, and should we direct askers there?

Comment: That tag was created [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65967/why-is-the-compiler-design-proposal-on-hold), back in September 2010. Area51 did not have a meta/discussion zone back then, it was added only in January 2011 as can be seen [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1/revisions). (revisions of first post ever made there, which is something I've never seen before, but the date does not lie. :))

Answer (score 1):

Questions about a proposal should always go in the *Area 51 Discussions* site, which now became more like a meta site for *Area 51*. (In fact, there is also an [area51-meta](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area51-meta) tag that is included between the obligatory tags.)

I would redirect users to the *Area 51 Discussions* site, maybe saying it's preferable to discuss about proposals there.